# in JS I can't get HTML into a div

Tags: javascript, html, variable-assignment

In this example the string information ssadf is input into the div but  and  do not. ???

```
<html>
<tr>
<div id="minus0"></div>
</tr>
</html>

<script type="text/javascript" >
document.getElementById("minus0").innerHTML   = '<TD>ssadf</TD>'
</script>
```

Comment: `div` is not a permitted content in `tr`, and `td` is not a permitted content in `div`.

Answer (score 2):

Element `div` is not allowed inside `tr` tags. Chrome will automatically remove the `tr` tag and your code will work. In other environments, you need to follow the rules.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As Teemu said "div is not a permitted content in tr, and td is not a permitted content in div". Please replace your code for this ->

```
document.getElementById("minus0").innerHTML   = '<p>ssadf</p>';
```

Hope this will help you

Answer (score 0):

this is much better:

```html
<table>
<tr id="minus0"></tr>
</table>

<script type="text/javascript" >
document.getElementById("minus0").innerHTML = '<td>ssadf</td>'
</script>
```

1- don't use div in tr.
2- don't use td in div.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this ,

```
    <table>
        <tr id="minus0"> </tr>
    </table>

<script type="text/javascript" >
        document.getElementById("minus0").innerHTML   = '<td>ssadf</td>';
     </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

As per the rule div is not allowed inside tr tag as it is not the correct way to put html.
You can try this.

```js
document.getElementById("minus0").innerHTML = '<TD><div>ssadf</div></TD>'
```

```html
<table>
  <tr id="minus0"></tr>
</table>
```